# Как назначить псевдоним функции?

Tags: c++

Есть три функции

```
void operator delete(void * hPointer);
void operator delete(void * hPointer, size_t ulSize);
void operator delete[](void * hPointer, size_t ulSize);
```

которые вызывают один и тот же код. Для примера (и только для примера):

```
{
    hPointer=nullptr;
    return;
}
```

Можно было бы скопировать код для каждой функции, но лучше бы использовать систему псевдонимов. То есть для любого `delete` обязана вызываться одна и та же функция. Использование директив препроцессора исключено, потому что сигнатуры функций разные.

Comment: Зачем "скопировать код"? Пусть вторая и третья вызывают первую - почти никакого копирования кода.

Comment: @AnT не хочет компилироваться. Ошибка "delete-incomplete"

Comment: Это как это? Без кода невозможно сказать, что там у вас за delete incomplete.

Comment: Во-первых, если ваши функции заведомо будут состоять просто из вызова `kmfree`, то зачем огород городить? Это то повторение кода, от которого избавиться не получится. Во-вторых, так где же здесь "delete incomplete"?

Comment: @AnT https://yadi.sk/i/40PqPEo7Na3ujQ

Comment: @dokenai: Ну так... Читайте мой ответ - моя телепатия меня не подвела. С чего вы вдруг взяли, что надо делать `delete hPointer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто вызывайте первую функцию из остальных, и не будет [почти] никакого повторения кода

```
void operator delete(void * hPointer)
{
  // Общая реализация
}

void operator delete(void * hPointer, size_t ulSize)
{ 
  operator delete(hPointer);
}

void operator delete[](void * hPointer, size_t ulSize)
{
  operator delete(hPointer);
}
```

Только делать это надо правильно, т.е. с указанием имени функции. А имя это - `operator delete`. Подозреваю по вашему комментарию, что вы пытались делать `delete hPointer` во второй и третьей функции, что, разумеется, совсем не то.